# Can SOLR configuration files be located in parent folders?

Tags: solr, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I have configured the QueryElevation searchComponent of SOLR as documented here:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Unique_Key_Field

However, I would like to load the elevate.xml file from several folders *above* the default one.

I cannot get this to work... all of the following generate an error:

```
<str name="config-file">../../elevate.xml</str>
<str name="config-file">..\..\elevate.xml</str>
<str name="config-file">c:/elevate.xml</str>
<str name="config-file">c:\elevate.xml</str>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent#config-file):

Path to the file that defines query elevation. This file must exist in:

1. ${instanceDir}/conf/${config-file} , or
2. ${dataDir}/${config-file}